# Can't select active dependent chain drop down menu

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu, webdriver

my code is this, it is select from drop down menus, but when in "il seçiniz"
i got an error `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated`

why it cant select from this menu? can you please suggest any ways to achieve it?

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import  ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import urllib.request
import socket
import urllib.error
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import winsound
import time
PROXY=""
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://%s' % PROXY)
print('--proxy-server=http://%s' % PROXY)
chrome_driver = "C:/chromewebdriver/chromedriver.exe"
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver, chrome_options=chrome_options)   proxy li istem
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver)    #proxsiz istem
driver.set_page_load_timeout(25)  # sahibinden comun proxyden yüklenmesi için en fazla 25 saniye verir
driver.get("https://parselsorgu.tkgm.gov.tr/")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(1)
#-----------------kabul ediyorum butonuna basış
onay=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="terms-ok"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", onay)
#-----------------analiz butonuna basış
time.sleep(1)
onay=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="analyze-list-link"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", onay)
time.sleep(1.5)
#-------------------analiz tipinin seçimi
dpbox=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="analyze-type-region"]/div/select')
dpbox=Select(dpbox)
while len(dpbox.options) == 0:
    continue
dpbox.select_by_visible_text('Bağımsız Bölüm Satış')
#-------------------analiz tipinin seçimi
dpbox=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="analyze-type-region"]/div/select')
dpbox=Select(dpbox)
while len(dpbox.options) == 0:
    continue
dpbox.select_by_visible_text('Bağımsız Bölüm Satış')
#-------------------yıl seçimi 2018
dpbox=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="year-region"]/div/select')
dpbox=Select(dpbox)
while len(dpbox.options) == 0:
    continue
dpbox.select_by_visible_text('2018')
#-------------------il seçimi ankara
dpbox=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="province-select"]')
dpbox=Select(dpbox)
while len(dpbox.options) == 0:
    continue
dpbox.select_by_visible_text('Ankara')
time.sleep(100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In web there are two element with `@id="province-select"`, which the first invisible and the second is visible, and your locator :

```
dpbox=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="province-select"]')
```

This is refer to first element, so please try change this line with locator `(//*[@id="province-select"])[2]` to refer the second element I mean and add `WebDriverWait` for make sure the element ready to click, import this :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
```

Try this :

```
dpbox.select_by_visible_text('2018')

time.sleep(1)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '(//*[@id="province-select"])[2]')))
dpbox=driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//*[@id="province-select"])[2]')
dpbox=Select(dpbox)
while len(dpbox.options) == 0:
    continue
dpbox.select_by_visible_text('Ankara')
```

Comment: Thanks Frian, you are solved! with this xpath"//*[@id="province-select"])[2]" everything solved. i did not understand meaning of "[2]" but it runs.. regards